# How to register a 'DataSourceFactiry' with 'Geo Server'?

Tags: geoserver, geotools

If I have written my own `DataSourceFactory`, then how can Geo Server recognize my `dataSourceFactory`? As I know that if we register with *org.geotools.data.DataStoreFactorySpi* then automatically *Geo Server* recognizes our data source. But I don't know how to register with *Geo Server*. I am planning to create a Java project (mvn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are implementing a store you can follow the tutorial at:
http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/datastore/index.html
(GeoServer expects to find GeoTools data stores).

In particular, the answer to your specific question is at the bottom of this page, you have to register it in a META-INF/services/org.geotools.data.DataStoreFactorySpi file:

http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/datastore/source.html